# Install lldb only in llvm

Tags: linux, llvm, lldb, llvm-clang

I'm starting to work with llvm infrastructure, and i'm interested in the use of the debugger tool [**lldb**](http://lldb.llvm.org/) instead of default **gdb**. I followed the tutorial of installation of [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) (Linux System, through svn options) and now wanted to know if is possible to install **lldb** only, instead of rebuild the whole structure of **llvm**. I don't found a especific documentation for that and i don't know any especific forum for llvm, so if anyone know some forum of llvm,

Sorry about my english, i'm a brazilian developer.

Comment: If you are on debian/ubuntu, you might be interested in http://llvm.org/apt/

Comment: I already see this article @HongxuChen, isn't exactly what i'm looking for, because i already have installed the binaries for **llvm** and **clang** with the most recent versions of **svn** repositories. If i follow these steps, probably the binaries will be replaced by older versions (stable).

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the solution yesterday, but was not sure how the policies to answer your own questions work here, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) it's allright. :)

In fact, it is quite simple.

First, you must identify the directory 'src-root' of the installation of the tools llvm/clang using the command 'llvm-config':

```
llvm-config --src-root
```

Once you find the directory, you must navigate to the path `$src-root/tools` and checkout the **lldb**:

```
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk lldb
```

The next step is go to the build directory, if the steps of the [tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary) has been followed, is just necessary to clean the build directory:

```
rm -rf *
```

Now, is the step of building the **lldb**, I personally have used the `autoconf` options (classical `configure make && make install`), but **cmake** can be used as well. When the `configure script` runs, the binaries of **llvm** and **clang** already installed will be detected, avoiding rebuild the whole structure of llvm/clang.

The parameters of the `configure script` can be changed, I use as follow because I intend to use the **llvm** libraries:

```
../llvm/configure --enable-optimized --enable-assertions --enable-shared --enable-targets=host
```

Then:

```
make -j4
sudo make install
```

where `-j4` option is the number of threads (jobs) to be created.

Reference: http://www.felixmorgner.ch/en/blog/building-clang-lldb-and-libc-on-ubuntu/